# Alternative Method to Polling/Trigger a Table in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, polling

I have a db on Oracle 11g where there's a table updated by external users. Now I want to catch the insert/update/delete on this table in order to bring these changes on a table on another db and I'm trying different methods for research. I tested polling (a job to check every minute if there is an update, insert or delete on the table) and trigger (fire on update, insert or delete on the table) yet, so are there alternative methods?

I found AOQ (Oracle Advanced Queuing), DBMS_PIPE, Oracle SNMP Agent Integrator Polling Activity, but I don't know if they are right for this case...

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

Polling or triggers are often all you need depending on the volume of data involved, and the frequency of inserts/updates/deletes.

For example, the polling method might be as simple as adding a column which is set to 1 by default, and updated to NULL when the row is "consumed" by the replication code. A trigger on the table would set it back to 1 if a row is updated. An index on this column would be lightweight (the index would only include entries for rows where the column is 1) and therefore fast to query. You'd need another table to handle deletes, though.

The trigger method would merely write insert/update/delete rows into a log table of some sort, which would then get purged periodically by a job.

For heavier volumes solutions include Oracle GoldenGate and Oracle Streams: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/focus-areas/data-integration/index.html